# update trigger to update records in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have on User_Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User_TB]
  (
    [User_Id] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [User_FullName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [User_Address] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [User_Gender] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [User_Joindate] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [User_Email] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [User_Branch] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [User_TeamLeader] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [User_Department] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [User_Position] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TID] [int] NULL
  )
```

Break_Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Break_TB]
  (
     [Break_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [User_Id] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
     [Date] [date] NULL,
     [Break_Time] [int] NULL,
     [Status] [varchar](50) NULL,
     [Late_time] [int] NULL,
     [TL_Id] [varchar](15) NULL,
     [start_Time] [time](7) NULL,
     [end_Time] [time](7) NULL,
 )
```

Log_Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log_TB]
 (
   [User_Id] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
   [First_Login] [time](0) NULL,
   [Logout] [time](0) NULL,
   [Date] [date] NULL,
   [Working_Hrs] [time](0) NULL,
 )
```

Now what am trying to do is that whenever the User_Id from User_Table is Updated , I want trying to update User_Id of Another two tables,

I have written trigger for that

```
Alter TRIGGER [dbo].[updateUserId] on [dbo].[User_TB]
 FOR Update
 AS 
 declare @Branch_Name varchar(50),
 @User_Id varchar(15) 

 select @User_Id = i.User_Id from inserted i;

 Update Break_TB set User_Id = @User_Id where User_Id = @User_Id;
 Update Log_TB set User_Id = @User_Id where User_Id = @User_Id;
```

But

It only updates records from Break_TB, It not works for Log_TB

Am not very good at triggers, if am wrong please Help me.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `select @User_Id = i.User_Id from inserted i;` - it's non-deterministic, you get **one, arbitrary** row, and you ignore all others. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: can you please tell me how to fix it @marc_s

Comment: What is the datatype of the user_id column in log_tb?

Comment: Also, your two update statements do nothing - they update the value to what it already is.

Comment: For user_Id In all tables is Varchar@Bohemian

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like this - a **set-based** solution that takes into account that in an `UPDATE` statement, you might be updating **multiple rows** at once, and therefore your trigger also must deal with multiple rows in the `Inserted` and `Deleted` tables.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[updateUserId] 
ON [dbo].[User_TB]
FOR UPDATE
AS 
    -- update the "Break" table - find the rows based on the *old* User_Id
    -- from the "Deleted" pseudo table, and set it to the *new* User_Id
    -- from the "Inserted" pseudo table
    SET User_Id = i.User_Id 
    FROM Inserted i
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.TID = d.TID
    WHERE
        Break_TB.User_Id = d.User_Id

    -- update the "Log" table - find the rows based on the *old* User_Id
    -- from the "Deleted" pseudo table, and set it to the *new* User_Id
    -- from the "Inserted" pseudo table
    UPDATE Break_TB 
    SET User_Id = i.User_Id 
    FROM Inserted i
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.TID = d.TID
    WHERE
        Break_TB.User_Id = d.User_Id
```

This code **assumes** that the `TID` column in the `User_TB` table is the **primary key** which remains the same during updates (so that I can join together the "old" values from the `Deleted` pseudo table with the "new" values after the update, stored in the `Inserted` pseudo table)

Comment: no @marc_s TID is not primary key and am trying to update those records after UPDATE not after insert or delete

Comment: @ChetanBodke: when you do an `UPDATE`, then the **old** values are present in the `Deleted` table, and the **new** values (after the update) are present in the `Inserted` table - this does **NOT** mean you're doing an insert and delete operation - this ***IS*** an `UPDATE` !! Also: what **is** the primary key for `User_TB` in that case??

Comment: User_Id is itself primary key

Comment: @ChetanBodke: but that's changing in the `UPDATE` - which is a really bad idea for a primary key!! You should have some fixed primary key that **doesn't change** over time!

Comment: ok .. @marc_s i will take look into that.. can you please help now to fix current problem

Comment: @ChetanBodke: if you have no fixed primary key, you **CANNOT** do this. Period. You need to be able to join the old and new values based on **some fixed non-changing key** in order to do this (as shown in my code). If you don't have such a key, you cannot do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77960/discussion-between-chetan-bodke-and-marc-s).