# SQL Server - update field in one table and updated related fields in multiple other tables, trigger, stored procedure or combination of both?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I'm working on a college problem and need to create a stored procedure to soft-delete a record in one table and the associated records in other tables. I'm trying to figure out how I might approach this and hence here I am.

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customers 
(
    Cust_ID varchar(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    IsDeleted bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    Contact_ID varchar(12) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY,
    Status_ID varchar(12) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY,
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerContactDetails 
(
    Contact_ID varchar(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    IsDeleted bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerStatus 
(
    Status_ID varchar(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    IsDeleted bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.AccountDetails 
(
    Account_ID varchar(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    IsDeleted bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,       
    Contact_ID varchar(12) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY,
    Cust_ID varchar(12) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY,
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Transactions 
(
    Transaction_ID varchar(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    IsDeleted bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    Account_ID varchar(12) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY,
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Associations  
(
    Association_ID varchar(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    Company_Name varchar(12) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY, (uses Cust_ID in dbo.Customers)
    IsDeleted bit DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    AssociatedCompany varchar(12) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY, (uses Cust_ID in dbo.Customers)
);
```

As you can see, all of these tables have an `IsDeleted` column set with the data type `bit` and defaults to 0 (to allow for soft deletes). What I'm trying to achieve is that when `dbo.Customers(IsDeleted)` is updated to bit 1, the following records automatically update to bit 1 also:

- dbo.CustomerContactDetails(IsDeleted)
- dbo.CustomerStatus(IsDeleted)
- dbo.AccountDetails(IsDeleted)
- dbo.Transactions(IsDeleted)
- dbo.Associations(IsDeleted)

My initial thought is to set up a stored procedure to allow the end-user to easily update the `dbo.Customers(IsDeleted)` column and then a trigger to update the related records but I'm not clear if this is the best approach and if so where to start.

My research into solving the problem so far has further confused me as it seems I need to be very careful that my code restricts the update of the `IsDeleted` columns **ONLY** as a standard stored procedure/trigger will affect all columns in a row.

Any guidance here is greatly appreciated.

Edited with the below (work in progress).

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[DeleteCustomer]
(
    @Cust_ID varchar(12)

) AS

    set nocount on;

    begin transaction 

    begin try

    UPDATE dbo.Customers
    SET IsDeleted = 1
    WHERE Cust_ID = @Cust_ID

    UPDATE ccd
    SET IsDeleted = 1 
    FROM dbo.CustomerContactDetails ccd
    INNER JOIN dbo.Customers C ON ccd.Contact_ID = C.Contact_ID
    WHERE c.Cust_ID = @Cust_ID

    UPDATE cs
    SET IsDeleted = 1 
    FROM dbo.CustomerStatus cs
    INNER JOIN dbo.Customers C ON cs.Status_ID = C.Status_ID
    WHERE c.Cust_ID = @Cust_ID

    UPDATE ad
    SET IsDeleted = 1 
    FROM dbo.AccountDetails ad
    INNER JOIN dbo.Customers C ON ad.Cust_ID = C.Cust_ID
    WHERE c.Cust_ID = @Cust_ID 

    UPDATE T
    SET IsDeleted = 1 
    FROM dbo.Transactions T
    INNER JOIN dbo.AccountDetails AD ON t.Account_ID = AD.Account_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Customers C ON ad.Cust_ID = C.Cust_ID
    WHERE c.Cust_ID = @Cust_ID

    UPDATE AA
    SET IsDeleted = 1 
    FROM dbo.Associations AA
    INNER JOIN dbo.Customers C ON AA.Company_Name = C.Cust_ID 
                            OR AA.AssociatedCompany = C.Cust_ID
    WHERE c.Cust_ID = @Cust_ID
    end try

    begin catch
    rollback transaction 
    throw
    end catch
```

I've successfully created my stored procedure but when I execute nothing happens. The screen just says 'executing' and it stays like that until I stop it. Any ideas?

```
USE [db]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[DeleteCustomer]
        @Cust_ID = N'C1'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure DeleteCustomer, Line 2
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.

Comment: What do you mean that a "standard stored procedure/trigger will affect all fields in a row"??

Comment: @SeanLange I'm struggling to find a link to the page now but it seemed to suggest that If I I write a proc to update the IsDeleted field in dbo.customers I would need incorporate into my proc that all other fields need to remain the same. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273982/update-trigger-to-update-records-in-another-table) discusses issues with one row to multiple row updates.

Comment: @MatBailie Company_Name and AssociatedCompany are both referencing Cust_ID in dbo.Customers. Each of these 3 attributes have the data type varchar(12).

Comment: Not sure why you would need to ensure that all other columns remain the same. But if you wrote a Customers_Delete procedure it could be coded to only change the IsDeleted column. If you use a trigger be sure you don't use scalar variables. Your logic needs to be set based.

Comment: @SeanLange none of my data is to be hard deleted from my database, hence the use of the IsDeleted attributes. To view the non-deleted data, the user would create a view along the lines of SELECT * WHERE IsDeleted <> 1. So, I need to change the IsDeleted attribute in my tables to flag that a data row is deleted but not alter any of the other data as this needs to remain in the DB. The best use case I can think of would be a customer for Sky closing down their account. Sky would want a way to exclude non-active customer data but keep the data their should the customer sign up again in future.

Comment: I understand the soft delete. Create a procedure to "delete". I would name it Customers_Delete. And it would just update the customer row(s) you need to "delete". It could also "delete" any data in the related tables. Pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange. Could you validate my recent edit as a viable solution?

Comment: Not quite. You don't want to pass in the value for the bit column. You KNOW it is going to become 1. That is what IsDeleted means right? What you need to pass in is the Cust_ID so you know **which** customer you are trying to "delete".

Comment: Oh and your transaction logic is not going to work here at all. You issue a rollback anytime there is an error. But there is no transaction that is started. And you never have a commit either. Consider what would happen if an update failed. It would try to rollback and crash because there is no transaction. And if there was one you don't want to have the first update succeed and the second one fail right? You want ALL of them to either succeed or fail as a group.

Comment: Ouch...trying to help you fix this your code is all over the place. You are setting Active to 1 in the Customers table....in your posted ddl there is no column with that name. And wow those tables need some help. CustomerStatus should be a lookup table and the primary key there would be a foreign key in the Customers table. Your whole design is very problematic because most of your tables end up being a 1:1 relationship.

Comment: My bad, Active should not be there that's a typo. Maybe I'm beyond help...

Comment: You aren't beyond help!!! And unlike so many others you are actually trying to figure it out as opposed to those who toss up some vague question and expect others to solve it for them. So kudos to you for being an active participant in your question. I will throw together something to demonstrate the concept of how this work. But given the nature of your tables it won't be 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use a trigger on your `Customers` table to update the related tables whenever `Customers.is_deleted` is changed. SQL Server provides `inserted` and `deleted` virtual tables in triggers, so you can compare to see whether `is_deleted` has changed, and update the other tables as necessary.

However, I'm wondering if you actually need additional `is_deleted` fields for your "child" tables. If, for example, `CustomerContactDetails.is_deleted` is always going to match `Customers.is_deleted`, you could just create a view that has all the contact details, and pull the `is_deleted` value from the base `Customers` table.

If you do go the route of creating a trigger, I would just recommend reading over the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: thank you for the response. Your suggestion seems logical, although I've already created my tables and written my report so I'm reluctant to start moving backwards with `UPDATE` statements to remove the `IsDeleted` columns from my tables and re-work my report to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This would likely work, you would of course need to provide inputs for the rest of the tables with their proper relationship keys.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Update_IsDeleted
ON dbo.Customers
AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF UPDATE(dbo.Customers)
    UPDATE  CustomerContactDetails
    SET     IsDeleted = Inserted.IsDeleted
    FROM    Inserted
    WHERE   CustomerContactDetails.Contact_ID = Inserted.Contact_ID
```

[This](http://sqlhints.com/2016/02/28/inserted-and-deleted-logical-tables-in-sql-server/) is a decent explination of `Inserted` Logical Tables if interested.

Comment: See my original post edited. I'm trying to understand your suggestion. Will it work as I've written it above? Not sure how to continue on the trigger to work on all tables. Also, you're referencing `WHERE CustomerContactDetails.Contact_ID = Inserted.Contact_ID` but this is not the field I need to change. I can't work out if you're just trying to demo the syntax or if I indeed need to reference this table and column being that it's the link back to `dbo.Customers`.

Comment: The `Inserted` table holds the recently inserted or updated values meaning the new data values that were just changed. Therefore newly added or updated records are inserted into the `Inserted` table. The link in my answer explains `Inserted` tables far better than I could in a comment anyway. As far as the Procedure is concerned, it works quite differently than a trigger would. But, it looks like you're on the right track to do it the way you're attempting to. @SeanLange seems to be guiding you pretty well in that area. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should be fairly close. I would caution you though, your table structures are problematic in a number of ways. One of the biggest issues to me is that you have Cust_ID as a varchar(12) but you don't have a column for customer name. Then you have referenced this Cust_ID as foreign key in other tables. I am assuming this column is really the customer name. And the issue is that you have designed your tables in such a way that you can't change a customer name once it is created. That is generally not a good approach as people and business names can change. At any rate that is a topic for another day.

```
CREATE PROC DeleteCustomer
(
    @Cust_ID varchar(12)
) AS

    set nocount on;

    begin transaction 

    begin try --we want ALL data to be updated or NONE of it so we use a single try/catch block

        UPDATE dbo.Customers
        SET IsDeleted = 1
        WHERE Cust_ID = @Cust_ID

        --we don't want to update this table. It looks like a lookup table.
        --UPDATE dbo.CustomerStatus
        --SET DeactivationDate = GETDATE()
        --WHERE @IsDeleted=IsDeleted

        UPDATE ccd
        SET IsDeleted = 1 
        FROM dbo.CustomerContactDetails ccd
        INNER JOIN dbo.Customers C ON ccd.Cust_ID = C.Cust_ID
        WHERE c.Cust_ID = @Cust_ID

        UPDATE cs
        SET IsDeleted = 1 
        FROM dbo.CustomerStatus cs
        INNER JOIN dbo.Customers C ON cs.Status_ID = C.Status_ID
        WHERE c.Cust_ID = @Cust_ID

        UPDATE ad
        SET IsDeleted = 1 
        FROM dbo.AccountDetails ad
        INNER JOIN dbo.Customers C ON ad.Cust_ID = C.Cust_ID
        WHERE c.Cust_ID = @Cust_ID

        UPDATE T
        SET IsDeleted = 1 
        FROM dbo.Transactions T
        INNER JOIN dbo.AccountDetails D ON T.Account_ID = D.Account_ID
        INN
        WHERE c.Cust_ID = @Cust_ID

        --you can do this with a single update instead of two by using a conditional OR in your join predicate
        --I would STRONGLY suggest that you don't interchange Company_Name and Cust_ID. A column name should not change between tables like that.
        UPDATE AA
        SET IsDeleted = 1 
        FROM dbo.Associations AA
        INNER JOIN dbo.Customers C ON AA.Company_Name = C.Cust_ID 
                                OR AA.AssociatedCompany = C.Cust_ID
        WHERE c.Cust_ID = @Cust_ID
    end try

    begin catch
        rollback transaction 
        throw --this will rethrow the exception so that you can handle it in your calling application
    end catch
```

Comment: that's awesome thanks. So close now, it just doesn't like this:

Comment: `UPDATE T
    SET IsDeleted = 1 
    FROM dbo.Transactions T
    INNER JOIN dbo.AccountDetails D ON T.Account_ID = D.Account_ID
    WHERE D.Account_ID = @Account_ID`

You originally had `WHERE c.Cust_ID = @Cust_ID` but `Cust_ID`  doesn't exist in the transactions table. `Account_ID` links `dbo.Transactions`  and `dbo.Accounts`. Trying the above instead, I'm getting the following error:

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure DeleteCustomer, Line 39
Must declare the scalar variable "@Account_ID".

Comment: When I try to declare another variable it also doesn't like that. So, how would I do this if the table doesn't have a direct key relationship with the source?

Comment: Also, I actually do have a column for CustomerName I've just omitted it from my question (as well as plenty others) as I thought it'd be easier to understand what I was trying to achieve. In hindsight that may not have been the best move. In my associations table I need to show which customers provide services to which customers, hence I thought changing the attribute names but linking back to the `Cust_ID` would allow me to explicitly show this relationship easily. I do take your point though, thanks.

Comment: Understand about simplifying for posting, makes total sense. :) As for updating tables that don't have a direct link you need to figure out how to join the tables. I am guessing that in this case you would need to join from AccountDetails to Customers?